# parameterized query issue with multiple conditions

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

I am trying to create a parameterized sql query with multiple conditions. I'm opening a command on entity framework version 2.2 and MSSQL 2016 which uses the module System.Data.Common.DbCommand

when I'm changing the **AND** right after **@tenantName** to an **OR**, the sql command works. I need it to be an **AND** statement to get the correct numbers.

The following sql command code is not working but it does work in sql management studio

```
var command = _context.Database.GetDbConnection().CreateCommand();
command.Transaction = _context.Database.CurrentTransaction.GetDbTransaction();

command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@tenantName", tenantName));
command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@searchTerm", searchTerm));
command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@hashedSearchTerm", hashedSearchTerm));

command.CommandText = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM dbo.IdpUserEventLog WHERE " +
"(TenantName IS NOT NULL AND TenantName = @tenantName) AND (" +
"(EventType IS NOT NULL AND EventType LIKE '%@searchTerm%') " +
"OR (AppName IS NOT NULL AND AppName LIKE '%@searchTerm%') " +
"OR (EventExtra IS NOT NULL AND EventExtra LIKE '%@searchTerm%') " +
"OR (EventDescription IS NOT NULL AND EventDescription LIKE '%@searchTerm%') " +
"OR (EventResultReport IS NOT NULL AND EventResultReport LIKE '%@searchTerm%') " +
"OR (EventDescription IS NOT NULL AND EventDescription LIKE '%@hashedSearchTerm%') " +
"OR (EventExtra IS NOT NULL AND EventExtra LIKE '%@hashedSearchTerm%')) " +
```

Comment: What do you mean by "not working". Just replacing `AND` with `OR` does not make a query functional or dysfunctional. The query will still execute, but the results may not be as desired. But that's impossible to say without any example data ...

Comment: Your query is malformed. Check this example from MSDN to build your query using entity framework: https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/ef/how-to-execute-a-parameterized-entity-sql-query-using-entitycommand

Comment: `TenantName IS NOT NULL AND` can be removed since it does nothing. Same for most of the null checks.

Comment: `'%@hashedSearchTerm%'` should be `@hashedSearchTerm`. And the `%` should be included in the value of `hashedSearchTerm` (in C#, not in the SQL). Same for the other likes.

Comment: What happens in your case is probably "short circuit evaluation". Ie the second part of your `WHERE` clause (ie anything after `AND`) will never evaluate to true (because of wrong `like` condition @mjwills mentioned), thus `condition1 AND condition2` will be false also. But when you use `condition1 OR condition2` the second part isn't evaluated at all (because if condition1 is already true, the whole expression becomes true, regardless of the result of condition2)

Comment: Side notes: you need to dispose the connection, command and transaction with `using`. I also urge you to use verbatim strings prefixed with `@` this allows you to put newlines inside the string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the comment from @mjwills and @derpirscher I'm now getting the same result as in sql management studio by changing the code to the following

```
var command = _context.Database.GetDbConnection().CreateCommand();
command.Transaction = _context.Database.CurrentTransaction.GetDbTransaction();

command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@tenantName", tenantName));
command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@searchTerm", $"%{searchTerm}%"));
command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@hashedSearchTerm", $"%{hashedSearchTerm}%"));

command.CommandText = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM dbo.IdpUserEventLog WHERE " +
"(TenantName = @tenantName) AND (" +
"(EventType LIKE @searchTerm) " +
"OR (AppName LIKE @searchTerm) " +
"OR (EventExtra LIKE @searchTerm) " +
"OR (EventDescription LIKE @searchTerm) " +
"OR (EventResultReport LIKE @searchTerm) " +
"OR (EventDescription LIKE @hashedSearchTerm) " +
"OR (EventExtra LIKE @hashedSearchTerm)) " +
```

Comment: Glad to hear it's now working. Don't forget to mark your question as answered to close it.


Comment: When I click on the check mark I get a error saying that I can accept my own answer in 2 days